What is the point of dual licensing a library under BSD-3-Clause and GPL?
While reviewing our libraries I stumbled over the zstd implementation (https://github.com/facebook/zstd/blob/dev/README.md).
It (and some of its derivatives) is dual licenses under a BSD-3-Clause and GPLv2 license.
This is fine for me, however, I was wondering:
As a library author, what are the reasons to do this?
The BSD-3-Clause is already more relaxed and compatible with GPLv2.
Why then would I dual-license my project with these two licenses?
(I chose the specific example above because it is "(c) Facebook" so I guess someone at that substantial company though this to be useful.)

Closely related: Can I use a library that is dual licensed GPL + LGPL as if it was only LGPL? ("It is redundant, in terms of permissions granted, to offer software under the GPL and under a GPL-compatible license simultaneously... However, it may be more convenient for a downstream GPL-licensed project to receive upstream code under the GPL proper to simplify licensing information...")

https://github.com/facebook/zstd/issues/3717#issuecomment-2133606421

It would appear that there is no point to it, apart from a formal "advantage" as noted in the comments above: "... it may be more convenient for a downstream GPL-licensed project to receive upstream code under the GPL proper to simplify licensing information ..."
The Zstd example in the question was answered on github and cites a legacy artifact:

terrelln commented May 28, 2024
Initially Zstd was licensed under BSD + PATENTS clause, which was not
compatible with GPL. Zstd was then dual licensed under GPL in order to
be merged into the Linux kernel. Later, the PATENTS clause was removed
from the BSD license.

So if licenses change, one may end up with a dual licensed project where the current combination does not make much sense anymore - but removing one of the licenses outright might be too much hassle.
